# how to log public, private and protected values in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, exception, laravel-5.5

As you can see below:

There are properties which are prefixed with `- or # or +`

[image]

```
- means Private
# means Protected
+ means public
```

How to access Public properties?

I can access private and protected properties for example: `getStatusCode()`

Also, its weird when I print `$e->getStatusCode()` it shows the value 400 but when I store it in an array or an object and try to log it nothing is sent.

Comment: You need to provide actual code and use case. This question makes no sense.

Comment: `$object->property` for public properties